# Do some airlines fail to carry enough bottled or distilled water for economy passengers?

Tags: in-flight-services

My company booked me on a Cathay Pacific flight. My colleague warned me that [in June 2015](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/news/Airlines-drinking-water-fails-hygiene-tests/)

> An investigation has been launched after drinking water on board 14 Cathay Pacific aircraft – around 10 per cent of its entire fleet – was found to be tainted.

> Hong Kong’s Port Health Office (PHO) collected samples from 22 planes, as part of a routine examination, earlier this month. Tests found that 14 of the samples failed to meet minimum hygiene standards.

> According to the airline, nine of the 14 affected aircraft have had their water tanks cleaned and disinfected, and the results of follow-up tests are pending. Tanks on the five other affected jets will be cleaned imminently. Hong Kong Aircraft Engineering Co, which transports water from supply stations to the aircraft, has cleaned all of its 11 vehicles.

> In the meantime Cathay Pacific is urging passengers not to brush their teeth in the plane lavatories and is handing out bottled water to everyone on board.

> [Cathay is providing bottled water for use on the affected planes and has sterilised nine of those jets' water tanks after samples of drinking water taken from them failed to meet hygiene standards in a recent test, the statement released last night said. The remaining five jets are due back in the city before tomorrow, and will be cleaned on their return.](https://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/hong-kong-economy/article/1826334/cathay-pacific-provides-bottled-water-flights-after)

When she flew with Cathay after this news story, she still distrusted Cathay's water. When she tried to request bottled water, Flight Attendant said that they don't have enough bottled water for all economy passengers, and that they are allowed to give out bottle water only to passengers with medical conditions. My colleague escalated to the Purser and In Flight Service Manager, and they all repeated this same position.

Can flight crew here confirm or deny this?

Comment: Carrying enough bottled water for all passengers when there is potable water in the fresh water tanks for multipurpose use would cost the airline a huge amount in additional fuel burn, so the answer to this is almost certainly “yes”.  Carrying bottled water for all passengers is only done when the potable water tanks are unavailable.

Comment: Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Moo: You make this sound like a universal - but I've been on plenty of flights (on other airlines) where all passengers were served bottled water.

Comment: @NateEldredge the question was “do some airlines...”, and my comment says “yes”.  Whats universal about that?  Some airlines will eat the fuel burn cost, some will not.  Some load food and beverages at one airport for the full round trip, others load them at either end.  Some tanker fuel around, others refuel at every stop.  Many airlines dont carry potable water tanks at all (reduces weight carried, reduces maintenance costs etc). It depends on the airlines policies.

Comment: @Moo: "is only done" made it sound like a practice that applies everywhere, that's all.

Comment: @Moo I thought because most airlines carry enough beverages (juices, soft drinks) for economy passengers, they'd carry enough bottled or distilled water too. I thought airlines considered bottled or distilled water as important as other beverages.

Comment: @js433o under international regulations, airlines have to supply drinking water - many airlines do this by carrying potable water tanks large enough for hand washing and drinking, in which case they typically wont carry enough bottled water for all passengers because its doubling up on the weight.  If the airline does not carry potable water tanks, or their size is not large enough, they will carry bottled water.  There is only so much weight an airline can carry around, and there is only so much space in the galley for storage.